# CodeIgniter 4 Css and Js 404 and 403

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-404, plesk

I had a running CI4 application and after some unfortunate events, I reinstalled the whole system on my server.

I was using Plesk on Centos 7, and now I and using Ubuntu 22.04. I created a subdomain, then uploaded my CI4 code.
I modified my `http.conf` and append `public` to the document root.

Next, I checked my `app/Config/App.php`

`public $baseURL = 'https://patron.berkyazilim.com/';`

My home page loaded but CSS files were not found.

I checked, I am using

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url('css/style.default.css') ?>">`

The file is available. But the file returns 404.

here my `public/css`

```
custom.css              style.default.css          style.green.min.css      style.pink.min.css.map  style.sea.css          style.violet.min.css
style.blue.css          style.default.min.css      style.green.min.css.map  style.red.css           style.sea.min.css      style.violet.min.css.map
style.blue.min.css      style.default.min.css.map  style.pink.css           style.red.min.css       style.sea.min.css.map
style.blue.min.css.map  style.green.css            style.pink.min.css       style.red.min.css.map   style.violet.css
```

I can load `custom.css` but `style.default.css` won't load.

see:

https://patron.berkyazilim.com/css/custom.css <- lodaing

https://patron.berkyazilim.com/css/style.default.css <- not loading

Here my `.htaccess`

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

        # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
        # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
        # RewriteBase /

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        #RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|assets/css|assets/js|assets/etc|robots\.txt)
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gestion/index.php/$1 [L]

        # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        # request to the front controller, index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

        # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
        ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one should not edit the HTTP config (`Nginx` or `Apache`) files that Plesk generates. For two reasons:

1. They won't work.
2. The files would be regenerated after each restart of the HTTP service.

Instead, just open your panel, go to `Domains-> Hosting & DNS -> Hosting` and there update your  Document root.

Doing that solved the problem...